# Building an embedded Windows OS for a variety of hardware platforms

Tags: windows-xp-embedded, windows-7-embedded

Is there any way to build an XP embedded OS or build a Windows 7 standard embedded OS to support a variety of motherboards with generic drivers that still function at an acceptable level? Mostly it has to support different graphics drivers, chipset, and a USB touch screen that has VGA input.

**EDIT**

I guess I am not being specific enough. I need to build one image that can auto-detect hardware and function correctly on a variety of chipsets, without rebuilding the OS image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP embedded and Windows 7 standard embedded are built with the xp and win7 binaries. It should support the same hardware and have the same drivers windows XP and win 7 have